# How to get word vectors from a gensim Doc2Vec?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I trained a gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec model
d2v_model = Doc2Vec(sentences, size=100, window=8, min_count=5, workers=4)
and I can get document vectors by
docvec = d2v_model.docvecs[0]

How can I get word vectors from trained model ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Doc2Vec inherits from Word2Vec, and thus you can access word vectors the same as in Word2Vec, directly by indexing the model:

```
wv = d2v_model['apple']
```

Note, however, that a Doc2Vec training mode like pure DBOW (`dm=0`) doesn't need or create word vectors. (Pure DBOW still works pretty well and fast for many purposes!) If you do access word vectors from such a model, they'll just be the automatic randomly-initialized vectors, with no meaning.

Only when the Doc2Vec mode itself co-trains word-vectors, as in the DM mode (default `dm=1`) or when adding optional word-training to DBOW (`dm=0, dbow_words=1`), are word-vectors and doc-vectors both learned simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the trained doc vectors, you can easily use 
`model.docvecs.doctag_syn0`. If you want to get the indexed doc, you can use `model.docvecs[i]`. 
If you are training a Word2Vec model, you can get `model.wv.syn0`.
If you want to get more, check this github issue link: (https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1513)